# Cent OS dropping connections after bad logon tries

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm new in Cent OS and in IP tables. Problem is that after some few failed authentication tries, server start to drop out connections. Only clues that i have are:

```
iptables -v -L -n  | grep 'LOGDROPOUT' 
    0    0    LOGDROPOUT    all     --     *    !lo 0.0.0.0/0 10.0.0.23
```

10.0.0.23 is my IP there are other listed.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config | grep 'LOGDROPOUT'
:LOGDROPOUT - [0:0]  
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG  --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked*" --log-uid
-A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG  --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked*" --log-uid
-A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG  --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked*" --log-uid
```

I did type it because I can connect just from a VM console .

My knowledge of  Cent OS and iptables are limited, but no one touch iptables lines. I don't know where to look to find  blocking rule.

Comment: check this link please: https://serverfault.com/a/563794/458296

Comment: thank you, but i don't have MaxAuthTries line, anyways I could delete all DENY rules, issue is from where rules are created